# Como fazer um select que retorne o resultado esperado

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados

Olá, tenho 3 tabelas no Mysql `Categorias`,`VideoContemCategoria` e `Videos`
Eu estou tentando fazer um `select` aonde eu retorne todas as categorias e junto com cada categoria retorne o último vídeo que foi publicado em relação a mesma.

Ex: E quero retornar algo como

> | Categoria | titulo | thumbnail 
>         Carros    ; Tesla motors ; img.png

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já tentei de varias formas com `Inner join` porém o fato de haver muitos vídeos associados com uma categoria acaba trazendo a mesma categoria varias vezes junto com os vídeos relacionados, enquanto só preciso da categoria com o último vídeo que foi registrado na mesma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se não possuir um campo na tabela de vídeo do tipo `criado_em` que apenas salva a data que o vídeo foi inserido (que seria o mais correto), você pode usar `MAX` no `id_video` (isso se levarmos em consideração que o maior id foi o ultimo a ser inserido, se a sua tabela tiver um garbage que recicla o id, essa logica morre. Por isso o ideal seria um campo criado_em) e dar um `GROUP BY` no `id_categoria`.

Estou supondo o seu schema esta assim:

```
CREATE TABLE Video
  (id_video int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, thumbnail varchar(7), titulo varchar(55),PRIMARY KEY(id_video));
CREATE TABLE Categoria
  (id_categoria int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, categoria varchar(55),PRIMARY KEY(id_categoria));
CREATE TABLE CategoriaVideo
  (id_video int, id_categoria int,
  FOREIGN KEY (id_video) REFERENCES Video(id_video),
  FOREIGN KEY (id_categoria) REFERENCES Categoria(id_categoria));
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------*/  
INSERT INTO Video (thumbnail, titulo) VALUES ("Teste1","TesteCategoria1");
INSERT INTO Video (thumbnail, titulo) VALUES ("Teste2","TesteCategoria1");
INSERT INTO Video (thumbnail, titulo) VALUES ("Teste3","TesteCategoria2");
INSERT INTO Video (thumbnail, titulo) VALUES ("Teste4","TesteCategoria3");
INSERT INTO Video (thumbnail, titulo) VALUES ("Teste5","TesteCategoria3");
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
INSERT INTO Categoria (categoria) VALUES ("Categoria1");
INSERT INTO Categoria (categoria) VALUES ("Categoria2");
INSERT INTO Categoria (categoria) VALUES ("Categoria3");
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
INSERT INTO CategoriaVideo (id_video, id_categoria) VALUES (1,1);
INSERT INTO CategoriaVideo (id_video, id_categoria) VALUES (2,1);
INSERT INTO CategoriaVideo (id_video, id_categoria) VALUES (3,2);
INSERT INTO CategoriaVideo (id_video, id_categoria) VALUES (4,3);
INSERT INTO CategoriaVideo (id_video, id_categoria) VALUES (5,3);
```

Sua query ficaria assim:

```
SELECT MAX(V.ID_VIDEO) AS ID_VIDEO, C.ID_CATEGORIA, C.CATEGORIA, V.TITULO, V.THUMBNAIL FROM Video AS V 
INNER JOIN CategoriaVideo AS VC ON V.ID_VIDEO = VC.ID_VIDEO 
INNER JOIN Categoria AS C ON C.ID_CATEGORIA = VC.ID_CATEGORIA
GROUP BY C.ID_CATEGORIA;
```

Tentei criar um exemplo no sqlfiddle, mas não consegui, testei na minha maquina e funcionou perfeitamente:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Se aderir ao campo criado_em, pode fazer assim:

```
CREATE TABLE Video
  (id_video int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   thumbnail varchar(7),
   titulo varchar(55),
   criado_em timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, /* Desse modo 
   sempre que um novo campo for criado, esse campo já vem com o atual TIMESTAMP */
  PRIMARY KEY(id_video));
```

E estou emulando os seguintes timestamp na tabela video:

```
INSERT INTO `Video` (`id_video`, `thumbnail`, `criado_em`, `titulo`) VALUES
(1, 'Teste1', '2017-02-16 02:34:28', 'TesteCategoria1'),
(2, 'Teste2', '2017-02-15 02:34:28', 'TesteCategoria1'),
(3, 'Teste3', '2017-02-16 02:34:28', 'TesteCategoria2'),
(4, 'Teste4', '2017-02-14 02:34:28', 'TesteCategoria3'),
(5, 'Teste5', '2017-02-05 02:34:28', 'TesteCategoria3');
```

Repare que o vídeo 4 da terceira categoria foi depois que o vídeo 5 (eu alterei manualmente para obter o efeito desejado), emulando a ação de um `Garbage Collector`

A nova query poderia ser executada assim:

```
SELECT MAX(V.CRIADO_EM) AS DATA_CRIACAO, C.ID_CATEGORIA, C.CATEGORIA, V.TITULO, V.THUMBNAIL FROM Video AS V 
INNER JOIN CategoriaVideo AS VC ON V.ID_VIDEO = VC.ID_VIDEO 
INNER JOIN Categoria AS C ON C.ID_CATEGORIA = VC.ID_CATEGORIA
GROUP BY C.ID_CATEGORIA;
```

O seu resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Muito bom @MarceloBonifazio, tentei local na minha maquia e não havia funcionada mas ao tentar no servidor compartilhado obtive sucesso, vlw mesmo me ajudou muito, até fiz engenharia reversa para entender como você fez, para que eu não passe mas por isso

Comment: Veja essa [revisão](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/184458/5) @joaopaulosantosalmeida acredito que deveria usar um id em CategoriaVideo, mas funciona sem, ai fica a seu critério

Answer (score 1):

Como dito pelo [Marcelo Bonifazio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/184458/64560), o ideal seria haver uma coluna que indicasse a data de upload do vídeo. Como não há, vou supor que último upload tem o maior identificador.

```
SELECT c.nome,
    v.titulo,
    v.thumbnail
FROM videos v
INNER JOIN VideoContemCategoria vcc ON v.id_video = vcc.id_video
INNER JOIN categorias c ON c.id_categoria = vcc.id_categoria
WHERE v.id_video IN
    (SELECT max(v.id_video)
     FROM videos v
     INNER JOIN VideoContemCategoria vcc ON v.id_video = vcc.id_video
     INNER JOIN categorias c ON c.id_categoria = vcc.id_categoria
     GROUP BY c.id_categoria);
```

Comment: Usei esse código, infelizmente por exemplo se um vídeo tiver 2 categorias, ele acaba retornando a mesma categoria duas vezes, criei um campo, tipo timeStamp na tabela vídeo, vou continuar correndo atrás, Muito obrigado @felipeMarinho